# How to integrate role based access token authentication for API methods generated using node-restful package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I am using the node-restful package for automatic API generation.
But I am not sure how to integrate role based access token validation for each of the automatically generated API methods GET, POST, PUT and DELETE

For Eg:

```
var Resource = app.resource = restful.model('resource', mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    year: Number,
  }))
  .methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);

Resource.register(app, '/resources');
```

I want admin to have access to all the above methods but a normal user should have access to only post and get method.

Please help me with this. Thanks.